# mvn dependency:copy from the cli

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use mvn dependency:copy from the cli (without having to make a pom) the purpose is to get the latest version of a specific artifact from either Nexus or the local .m2 and copy it to a specific location.

Currently I have this, but am kind of lost on the correct way to pass in the artifactItems list.

```
mvn dependency:copy \
    -DgroupId=some.group \
    -DartifactId=some.artifact \
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dtype=zip
```

Comment: Do you need that in a project? Yes than use a dependency or use the dependency plugin in this project..

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear from the documentation on the apache site, but with some experimentation I discovered that what you want is:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=some.group:some.artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:zip \
     -DoutputDirectory=MyFolder
```